# Solving generalized A*V = B*V*D with A and B being Hermitian gives COMPLEX eigenvalues in Matlab

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue

In Matlab, I have two 142 x 142 Hermitian complex matrices A and B, which are verified by

```
isequal(A,A')
ans =
       1
isequal(B,B')
ans =
       1
```

and

```
A-A'=(all exact zeros)
B-B'=(all exact zeros)
```

I tried to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem A*V = B*V*D by

```
[V,D] = eig(A, B);
```

and I expected for two things:

1. Real eigenvalues, V
2. Eigenvectors are orthogonal. That is, V'*B*V is an identity matrix.

However, I got COMPLEX eigenvalues and V'*B*V has nonzero value everywhere. Besides, things didn't change if I use the qz algorithm. Where can possibly go wrong? I have got stuck in this bottleneck for weeks. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of the imaginary components?  If it's small (1E-15 or lower depending), just get rid of them.

Comment: @TroyHaskin 
Yes, it's about that magnitude. However, I need correct orthogonal eigenvectors for further analysis. That's why I can't just throw the imaginary parts.

Comment: If you can come up with some (random) example of `A` and `B` then I can fully test my code and post an answer. Anyway, I agree with @TroyHaskin that the imaginary part is a small number which comes from the computation of `eig`. Try `eps(max(abs(A(:)))` to see to what order of magnitude will the result be in exact, aka below which number you can safely declare they are merely errors and just throw them away.

Comment: Agreed with @Yvon.  To proceed further we'll need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Although, I'll say again, if the non-zeros from the orthogonality test are "small", there might be nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

from matlab document:

> [V,D] = eig(A,B) returns diagonal matrix D of generalized eigenvalues and full matrix V whose columns are the corresponding right eigenvectors, so that A*V = B*V*D.

---

use following command for more accurate results :

```
 [V,D]=eig(A,B,'qz')
```

read the following document carefully  about situation where eig function does not return accurate results :
[Matlab Doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html)